# Why can't I replace a name column selector with a numeric column selector in nls()?

Tags: r

Writing a Shiny app and encountered this interesting problem.

In the program I pass in the user-selected columns of data, in this case for a regression. These are represented by x and y below.

As you can test below, nls() works fine if I replace the y variable with as.numeric(unlist(y_dat)) and leave the x variable the specific column name for the iris data set. But to generalize it for the program, I would like to do the same thing for x and use the column number. However, the exact same as.numeric(unlist()) approach doesn't work for x. I have tried a number of different approaches that all result with exactly the same structure in R-script and in debugging mode in Shiny, but I can't find anything that works other than explicitly typing the name of the column I want to use for x.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
data<-iris

x=3
y=2

x_dat=data[x]
y_dat=data[y]

fm0<-nls(formula = log(as.numeric(unlist(y_dat)))~log(a) + b*data$Petal.Length,start = list(a=1,b=1),data=data)#works
fm0


fm0<-nls(formula = log(as.numeric(unlist(y_dat)))~log(a) + b*as.numeric(unlist(x_dat)),start = list(a=1,b=1),data=data) #throws an error:

# Error in str2lang(x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
# 1: ~ 
#   ^
#   In addition: Warning messages:
#   1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# 2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: Try by extracting the column i.e. `fm0<-nls(formula = log(as.numeric(unlist(y_dat)))~log(a) + (b*x_dat$Petal.Length),start = list(a=1,b=1),data=data)`

Comment: It must be something related to matching the attribute in `- attr(*, "names")= chr "Petal.Length"`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for the response. That doesn't get me there, unfortunately. The user will have loaded their data and selected their column, so whatever the answer is would work for whatever data you load and whatever column numbers you enter. I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I understand, but why not create the column in the data and then you can do this without any `$` or `unlist`

Comment: What i meant is `nls(formula = log(as.numeric(unlist(y_dat)))~log(a) + b* Petal.Length,start = list(a=1,b=1),data=transform(data, Petal.Length = unlist(x_dat)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Define x_dat and y_dat to be vectors rather than data frames. The as.numeric does not seem to be needed in the example but if it were then it could be applied on each of the first two lines.

```
x_dat <- data[[x]]
y_dat <- data[[y]]
 
nls(log(y_dat) ~ log(a) + b * x_dat, start = list(a = 1,b = 1))
```

**2)** Another way is to define the formula in terms of the names.  as.numeric does not seem to be needed but if it were then apply it to data[[x]] and data[[y]] directly before the code below.

```
s <- sprintf("log(%s) ~ log(a) + b * %s", names(data)[y], names(data)[x])
nls(s, data, start = list(a = 1, b = 1))
```

Comment: It worked! What is weird is that I am sure I tried that at some point. What is interesting is that I now get warnings about x "Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf" but it does what I need for graphing purposes so maybe it is something else.